Why is my electron app showing this error when using API hosted on ngrok?
I built an Electron app just to serve as an interface to send messages to whatsapp. It consumes the API from NodeJS that I made, which uses the Venom Bot system (https://github.com/orkestral/venom).
I needed to expose my api so that I could use outside my localhost, so I used ngrok.
Everything works fine using localhost, I can send messages to an infinite amount of numbers successfully (using the app itself or swagger, for example) but when I change the url in the electron code to my ngrok link, if there is a decent amount of numbers, It doesn't send the messages to all the numbers, it breaks and then it shows the following error message:
1042560:error:1e000065:Cipher functions:OPENSSL_internal:BAD_DECRYPT:..\..\third_party\boringssl\src\crypto\fipsmodule\cipher\e_aes.c:1065:
  ] {
    library: 'Cipher functions',
    function: 'OPENSSL_internal',
    reason: 'BAD_DECRYPT',
    code: 'ERR_SSL_BAD_DECRYPT'
  }

Its 100% a problem with electron, cause when it breaks, if I don't stop the API manually, the messages keep being sent, until the end of the array of numbers.
My code from electron:
ipcMain.handle("sendMessage", async (event, messageData) => {
    try {
        const response = await axios.post(url + "/whatsapp/send", messageData, {
            headers: { Authorization: `Bearer ${global.authToken}` },
        });
        return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
        console.error(
            "Mensagem de erro:",
            error.response ? error.response.data : error.message
        );
        throw error;
    }
});

And the code from the API on NodeJS:
  public async sendMessage(to: string[], message: string): Promise<void> {
    if (!this.isClientInitialized) {
      console.error("Whatsapp client não foi iniciado!");
      throw new Error("Whatsapp client is not initialized");
    }
    this.currentNumber = to;
    for (let number of to) {
      this.currentTimer = Math.floor(Math.random() * (60000 - 30000 + 1)) + 30000;
      await sleep(this.currentTimer)
      number = number + "@c.us";
      await this.client.sendText(number, message);
    }
  }


I'm almost certain its a problem with ssl certificate with ngrok but the solutions I tried didn't work.
Solutions I've tried:
Putting this on main.js
app.on('certificate-error', (event, webContents, url, error, certificate, callback) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    callback(true);
});

and also:
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'DEV') {
    process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED = 0;
}

I need it to send all the messages independently of how many numbers I type using ngrok.
PS: I noticed that the electron app always stops working when it hits 5min of sending the messages. The amount of numbers I place doesn't change this fact. Also, I think its important to say that I implemented a delay between the messages, so to every number there is, the messages will be sent in an interval of 30 to 60 seconds to each number.

I changed from ngrok to pinggy and It's working just fine, but pingyy only allows free tunnels for 60 minutes, so fixing ngrok problem would be ideal haha

Hello! This is Scott from ngrok. This seems like strange behavior. I'm assuming you're using a free account and thus have a *.ngrok-free.app domain. All of these domains use the same wildcard cert. It could be a rate limit issue. Are you seeing this on your first request? Also, do you see the request in your ngrok Traffic Inspector? If you go to your ngrok dashboard--dashboard.ngrok.com--and select Traffic Inspector you should be able to see all the requests hitting your endpoint with possible error codes.

Hello Scott, I'll take a look at what you said, thanks for the response!
